# Does Thunder Buffer only work once per round?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, sorcerer, immediate-reaction

My friends and I recently had an issue with the sorceror ability [Thunder Buffer](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=5868).

> Daily,        Arcane
>
> Minor Action,      Personal
>
> Effect: Until the end of the encounter, you gain a +2 power bonus to
>   AC, and as an immediate reaction you can push each enemy that hits you
>   with a melee attack a number of squares equal to your Charisma
>   modifier.

I thought the ability worked as an immediate reaction once per round on an enemy that hits the sorceror with a melee attack.  However, the sorceror pointed out that the ability says **"each enemy that hits you"**.  He argues that he should be able to knock back every enemy that hits him with a melee attack in a given round.

So my question is, which is it?  Or does the ability work some other way entirely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Just once per round**

*Each* here is a once per round effect, unless you have a way to provide yourself with more than one immediate action in a round (I'm not aware of any right off hand). The *each* allows the trigger to be valid for the rest of the encounter.

The problem is that the action is described as an `immediate reaction`. `immediate actions` are defined as [once/round effects](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=glossary&id=120):

> Once per Round: You can take only one immediate action per round, either an immediate interrupt or an immediate reaction. If you take an immediate action, you can’t take another one until the start of your next turn, but you can’t take an immediate action on your own turn.

Comment: Additionally, if at some point a power came into existence that allowed more that one enemy to attack *at the same time*, this would push all of the simultaneously attacking enemy that hit.

Comment: That's how I thought it worked.  Thanks for clarifying why the "each" is in there.